# Firebase User IP Address

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ip

How can one acquire a users IP address when they are interacting with Firebase Real-time database? I have an iOS application that uses Firebase as its backend service and it allows for users to post things to a feed anonymously. If I wanted to trace back the users IP address to see who posted it, what is the best way of going about figuring that out?

Cheers!

Comment: Tracing back IP addresses is not a good way of identifying users; Due to NAT and proxying there could be hundreds or even thousands of users behind an IP address. Either your service allows anonymous posting (with all that that entails) or it doesn't in which case, make people register.